# Wordpress – Country Sensitive Post View

Tags: php, wordpress, geolocation, location, geo

I'm looking for a solution to display posts based on the viewers
location.

For Example: I'm writing an article and set an option so it is only
visible for users from within USA.
If a user in Germany is visiting the Wordpress page, the post does
not appear.

I don't want to change content within a post, but more hide and show
them with an option for the author.

If there is some plugin, that can do this, I would highly appreciate.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. Didn't found a plugin and wrote this to query post for country of visitor: (remember to get your key at http://ipinfodb.com/)

```
$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$request = 'http://api.ipinfodb.com/v3/ip-country/?key=  get your own key &ip='.$ip.'&format=json';
$response  = file_get_contents($request);
$jsonobj  = json_decode($response);                    
if ($jsonobj->countryCode == "SE"){
// args for query post for selected country $args = array ()
}
elseif ($jsonobj->countryCode == "PL"){
// args for query post for selected country $args = array ()
}
query_posts( $args );
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this discussion over here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26832/display-only-certain-posts-based-on-visitors-country. It might not give you a ready-to-use solution but maybe it helps as a pointer in the right direction.